How can I efficiently find the k-th node from the end and m-th node from the beginning of a singly linked list in one pass?
I'm working with a singly linked list in Java and need to implement a method that can simultaneously find the k-th node from the end and m-th node from the beginning of the list in a single traversal. The solution should be efficient and not require additional space beyond a few variables.
Here are the specific requirements:
Implement a method that can find the k-th node from the end and m-th node from the beginning in one pass through the linked list.
If the list doesn't have enough nodes (i.e., if k or m exceed the length of the list), handle this gracefully (e.g., return null or a default value).
For example, given the linked list 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 and k = 2 and m = 3, the method should return node 3 from the end (4) and node 3 from the beginning (3).
Here's a simplified version of my linked list implementation:
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class FindNodes {

public static ListNode[] findNodes(ListNode head, int k, int m) {
    // Implement the logic here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
    head.next = new ListNode(2);
    head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
    head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
    head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

    int k = 2;
    int m = 3;
    ListNode[] result = findNodes(head, k, m);

    if (result != null && result.length == 2) {
        System.out.println("K-th node from the end: " + result[0].val);
        System.out.println("M-th node from the beginning: " + result[1].val);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nodes not found.");
    }
}

}
How can I implement the findNodes method to efficiently find the k-th node from the end and m-th node from the beginning of the linked list in one pass? Any detailed explanation or code example would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to SO! This seems like a classic two-pointers problem; there are lots of great tutorials on the method out there.

Explanation:
To find the ( k )th node from the end and the ( m )th node from the start of a singly linked list using two pointers:

Initialize Two Pointers: Start both pointers at the head of the list.
Move First Pointer ( k ) Steps Ahead: Move the first pointer ( k ) steps forward.
Move Both Pointers Until First Reaches the End: Move both pointers one step at a time until the first pointer reaches the end. The second pointer will then be at the ( k )th node from the end.
Find the ( m )th Node from the Start: Move a third pointer ( m ) steps ahead from the head to reach the ( m )th node from the start.
Return the Nodes: Return the nodes pointed to by the second and third pointers.

Time Complexity: O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the list, as the list is traversed only once.
public static ListNode[] findNodes(ListNode head, int k, int m) {
    // Implement the logic here
    // Assuming both m and k to be less than or equal to the length of the linked list
    ListNode temp1 = head, temp2 = head, temp3 = head;
    ListNode[] ans = new ListNode[2];

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i<k){
        temp1 = temp1.next;
        i++;
    }
    while(j<m){
        temp3 = temp3.next;
        j++;
    }
    ans[1] = temp3;
    while(temp1 != null){
        temp2 = temp2.next;
        temp1 = temp1.next;
    }
    ans[0] = temp2;
    return head;
}


You could do this in one loop, iterating over the list's nodes while decreasing both m and k on each iteration:

We maintain a node reference which starts out as the head node, and advance it only when k is negative. That means it will not advance in the first k iterations, but will only advance n-k times in total, ending up at the kth last node.
When m becomes zero, then we have found the mth node.

    public static ListNode[] findNodes(ListNode head, int k, int m) {
        ListNode[] ans = { head, null };
        while (head != null) {
            if (--k  < 0) ans[0] = ans[0].next;
            if (--m == 0) ans[1] = head;
            head = head.next;
        }
        if (k > 0) ans[0] = null;  // k was out of range
        return ans;
    }

NB: the final if is only needed if it is not guaranteed that the arguments are valid positions in the linked list.

I've taken a liberty to edit for clarity; hope you won't disapprove. :)

Not at all. Thank you for this improvement of the text, Will!
